# Display student who's taking more than one subjects

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table like this.

```
StudentID | SubCode | SubName
-----------------------------
    1          M1       Math
    1          S1       Science
    1          E1       English
    2          H1       History
    2          G2       Geography
    4          M1       Math
```

I want a query that will display data like this..

```
StudentID | SubCode | SubName
-----------------------------
    1          M1       Math
               S1       Science
               E1       English
    2          H1       History
               G2       Geography
    4          M1       Math
```

***EDIT:***

Here is query I have created please see if you understand something. Really appreciate your response

```
SELECT 
 EI.[EmpCode], EI.[FirstName]+' '+EI.[LastName] [EmployeeName], EI.[FatherName], Dpt.[FullName] [Department],
 [Desig].[FullName] [Designation], EI.DOB [DateOfBirth], EI.DOJ [JoiningDate], EI.NCNIC [CNIC], EI.Mobile, EI.OfficialEmail,
 EI.Email, EI.Address, [Status].FullName [Status], [Company].FullName [Company], EI.EmpImage [Image], 
 [Academics].MajorSubjects, [Academics].DegreeInstituteName, [Academics].PassingYear, [Academics].CGPA, [Degree].[FullName] [DegreeName],
    CONVERT(varchar(3),DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOJ, GETDATE())/12) +' Year(s) '+
    CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOJ, GETDATE()) % 12)+ ' Month(s)' 
    AS [EXPERIENCE]


FROM [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeInfo] EI,  [HRM].[tbl_Designation] [Desig], HRM.tbl_Department [Dpt], 
[HRM].[tbl_EmployeeStatus] [Status], [AppCNF].[tbl_OrganizationCompany] [Company], [HRM].[tbl_Degree] [Degree],
[HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAcademic] [Academics]
WHERE [Desig].[ID] = EI.DesignationCode
AND
Dpt.ID = EI.[DeptCode]
AND
[Status].ID = EI.EmpStatusCode
AND
[Company].ID = EI.EmpCompanyCode
AND
[EI].ID = [Academics].EmpCode
AND
[Degree].ID = [Academics].[DegreeCode]
ORDER BY 1,4
```

Comment: Ok, but MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Fix it in the presentation layer instead.

Comment: @Sami I'd say this is irrelevant because no RDBMS specific functionality is need for this.

Comment: @Sami SqlServer.

Comment: @Filburt, some dbms specific features can be convenient here. A core ANSI SQL compliant query will be a bit tricky.

Comment: Is there anyway I could achieve this formatting ?

Comment: You *don't* do this.  In SQL *(and in set theory, etc)* the position of a row is meaningless.  In order to know something about a row the row must contain that information.  In your example `NULL, S1, Science` isn't for any student.  Yes, I know that ***you*** know it's student `1`, but that's not how SQL works.  As this is clearly for presenting data to a user, do the presentation formatting in the presentation layer of your application.  *(You want to make code so that it can be re-used.  Keep the data-access separate from formatting...)*

Comment: @MuhammadAsim Are you try my answer, what is the problem with that.

Comment: @DineshDB Thank you for your solution but unfortunately that didn't work out for me although I am able to understand your solution and it's purpose but my query in quite complex I guess. I can share my query here if you want but I'm not sure if I can share the database behind it.

Comment: @MuhammadAsim, sure can you please share your query

Comment: @DineshDB I have updated the question. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Student TABLE(StudentId CHAR(1), SubCode VARCHAR(2),SubName VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Student VALUES('1','M1','Math')
INSERT INTO @Student VALUES('1','S1','Science')
INSERT INTO @Student VALUES('1','E1','English')
INSERT INTO @Student VALUES('2','H1','History')
INSERT INTO @Student VALUES('2','G2','Geography')
INSERT INTO @Student VALUES('4','M1','Math')

SELECT CASE WHEN D.RN=1 THEN D.StudentId ELSE '' END StudentId
    ,D.SubCode,D.SubName
FROM(
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StudentId ORDER BY StudentId)RN 
    FROM @Student
    )D
ORDER BY
    D.StudentID, D.RN
```

**OutPut:**

```
StudentId   SubCode SubName
1           M1      Math
            S1      Science
            E1      English
2           H1      History
            G2      Geography
4           M1      Math
```

Comment: You ***really*** need an `ORDER BY` clause here, else there is ***NO*** guarantee the records will come out in the desired order.  Also, it's just a very, Very, ***Very***, bad idea to do presenation layer formatting in SQL.  If in the future there is ever a desire to re-use this query for some other similar purpose, but without the formatting, you instead have to write it again.  A maintenance nightmare, breaching DRY principles, etc, etc.  This *can* do it, with an ORDER BY, but *can* is not the same as *should*.